# How to compare rows in columns? - Spotfire

Tags: function, rows, spotfire

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/savR0.png)

How do you add a calculated column that identifies within the same groups of [WheelsetNumber], there is differing [W05Wheelset] values within the rows?

E.g. WheelsetNumber 100009 has KCLASS and GSHORT strings, I'd like it to return '1'. As opposed to 100920, where I want it to return '0' as all rows for 100920 have the same KCLASS strings in the [W05Wheelset] column. For wheelset numbers with one row, such as 100011, I want it to return '0' as well

I know I need to use a mixture of OVER functions but I'm out of my depth. Any help appreciated :)

Dataset attached

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you:

```
case  when Count([W05Wheelset])!=UniqueCount([W05Wheelset]) over ([WheelsetNumber]) then 1 else 0 end
```